# How to make button background color change animatedly when "enabled" changes?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Suppose there's an button defined as follows

```kotlin
val btnEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

...

Button(
  colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
    background = Color.Yellow
    disabledBackgroundColor = Color.Black ),
  enabled = btnEnabled

) {
...
}
```

When the value of `btnEnabled` is changed, the button's background will immediately change rigidly. Any way to make it an animated transition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try like this, set the button both background and disabled with the animated color

```kotlin
val isButtonEnabled = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
val animatedButtonColor = animateColorAsState(
    targetValue = if (isButtonEnabled.value) Color.Green else Color.Red,
    animationSpec = tween(1000, 0, LinearEasing)
)

Button(
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        backgroundColor = animatedButtonColor.value,
        disabledBackgroundColor = animatedButtonColor.value,
    ),
    enabled = isButtonEnabled.value,
    onClick = { }
) {
    Text(text = "Target")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the

```
  val animatedColor = animateColorAsState(
    if (btnEnabled.value) Color.Green else Color.Red )

Button(Modifier.background(animatedColor)){}
```

Or if you want to control over more options like duration;

```
 val transitionState = remember {
    MutableTransitionState(btnEnabled.value).apply {
        targetState = !btnEnabled.value
    }
}
val transition = updateTransition(transitionState, label = "transition")

val bgColorTransition by transition.animateColor(
        label = "colorTransition",
        transitionSpec = { tween(durationMillis = ANIMATION_DURATION) },
        targetValueByState = {
            if (btnEnabled.value) Color.Green else Color.Red
        }
    )

    Button(Modifier.background(bgColorTransition)){}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, The Modifier.background(color) does not affect the colors of button

Answer (score 1):

### In Material3:

It's changed a bit, you have to use `animateColorAsState` and set `containerColor` to change background color by animation.

#### Example:

```
fun myButton(isButtonEnabled : Boolean) {
               val animatedColor = animateColorAsState(
                 if (isButtonEnabled)
                  MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline
                    else
                  MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                     )
          Button(
                onClick = { //todo },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    containerColor = animatedColor.value, // your background color
                    contentColor = Color.Unspecified,
                    disabledContainerColor = Color.Unspecified,
                    disabledContentColor = Color.Unspecified
                ) 
            )
    }
```

##### source: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/ButtonDefaults#buttonColors(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)